# SQL to select IDs from table1 and update same IDs to table2

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables in a database called categories and categories_description.  In categories_description table I need to select all categories_id that categories_name equal 'Bearings'. Then with those selected categories_id numbers, update the categories_image in the categories table with 'bearings.jpg'.

I understand how to write code to select the categories_id, but am unsure how to use that selection to update those same categories_id in another table.

```
SELECT categories_id FROM categories_description WHERE categories_name = 'Bearings';
```

Now I need to update categories table at the categories_image at each id selected from above.

It should be something like this, but I am unsure how to tie them together.

```
UPDATE categories SET categories_image = 'bearings.jpg' WHERE categories_id = above statement
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IN`:

```
UPDATE categories 
SET categories_image = 'bearings.jpg' 
WHERE categories_id IN (
  SELECT categories_id 
  FROM categories_description 
  WHERE categories_name = 'Bearings'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this type of query with an `update`/`join` combination:

```
UPDATE categories c join
       categories_description cd
       on c.category_id = cd.category_id and
          cd.categories_name = 'Bearings'
    SET c.categories_image = 'bearings.jpg'
```

In your case, the major difference is performance. Older versions of MySQL sometimes do a poor job of implementing `in` with a `subquery`.

In general, though, the `join` syntax is a powerful way to express many updates, so it is worth learning about.

Comment: Thanks will took into join operations